# ARM Template with KeyVault - SQL vs. VM

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure ARM template which creates a SQL Server and a VM. Both refer to the KeyVault to get the Admin-Password:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "kind": "v12.0",
      "name": "[variables('vSqlServerName')]",
      "tags": {
        "Environment": "[parameters('pEnvironment')]",
        "DisplayName": "SQL Server",
        "UDID": "SQLServer" // Unique Deployment ID (for later reference) 
      },
      "apiVersion": "[variables('vSqlAPIVersion')]",
      "location":  "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[variables('vSqlAdminUser')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword":{
        "reference": {
          "keyVault": {
            "id": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('vKeyVaultName'))]"
          },
          "secretName": "SQLDW-AdminPassword"
        }
      },
        "version": "12.0"
      },
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vSqlVMName'), variables('vSuffixVM'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "Standard_DS5_v2"
        }
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[variables('vSqlVMName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[variables('vWinAdminUser')]",
          "windowsConfiguration": {
            "provisionVMAgent": true,
            "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
          },
          "secrets": [],
          "adminPassword": {
            "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('vKeyVaultName'))]"
              },
              "secretName": "VM-LocalAdminPassword"
            }
          }
        }
    }
]
```

this works just fine for SQL, but not for the VM
the error i get is this:
{
11:16:27 - [ERROR]         "target": "vm.properties.osProfile.adminPassword",
11:16:27 - [ERROR]         "message": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. 
11:16:27 - [ERROR] Path 'properties.osProfile.adminPassword', line 1, position 785."
11:16:27 - [ERROR]       },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Key Vault reference directly in the template with VM's for sure. So you have to use a parameter file for that.

So in your parameter file you would have:

```
...
"adminPassword": {
    "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/{}/resourceGroups/{}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{}"
        },
        "secretName": "secretName"
    }
},
...
```

and in the template:

```
"osProfile": {
  "computerName": "[variables('vSqlVMName')]",
  "adminUsername": "[variables('vWinAdminUser')]",
  "windowsConfiguration": {
    "provisionVMAgent": true,
    "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
  },
  "secrets": [],
  "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
}
```

And you would use the parameters file to supply parameters to the deploment, or, alternatively, you can convert VM deployment to a nested template deployment, that way you can pass parameters directly from your parent template, without parameters file.

Refer to [this example](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/parent.json#L177). It doesn't deal with VM's but the idea is the same.

Comment: I am aware of that and also the workarounds, I would just like to understand why it is possible for SQL Servers but not for VMs

Comment: well, i doubt anyone but the product group can tell you why it works for sql, but my answer definitely shows how its supposed to work

Comment: A number of RPs worked on RP specific solutions while we worked on a generic solution - so you'll see a few other resources work with KV in various ways that are likely now unnecessary given the generic solution.  So no, functional/technical reason, just everyone working at cloud velocity...